# What is the best way to get a property value from all json-ld objects on a page?

Tags: javascript, json-ld

I'm trying to pull all the mpn values from a product results page, where the data is stored in JSON-LD format.  Grabbing the top 10 values, is this the most ideal way to do it?

```
(function(){
var mpns=   document.querySelectorAll('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
var x = [];
mpns.forEach(
    function(value){
        var a = JSON.parse(value.innerText).mpn;
        x.push(a);
    }
);
return x.slice(0,10);
})();


<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Executive Anvil",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height.",
  "mpn": "925872",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no it's not good way . because if `mpns` array iength is in terms of 1000000 then what is the meaning of push if you want only first 10 element .

so try for loop instead